# Only reading part of command line argument

Tags: python

Whenever I give a number through the command line, let's say 92, it only takes the 9, completely ignoring the 2. Yet, if I use arg[1] it will use the 2 instead of the 9.
    import sys

```
for arg in sys.argv:
    print arg

print ""    
print "-----"
print ""    

try:
    argNumber = int(arg[0])
except ValueError:
    argNumber = 0
    print "This is wrong"

for i in range(argNumber, 0, -1):
    print i
```

Also, for some reason I can't add a print "This is wrong" line to the except ValueError. It gives me an indention error?

Comment: You mean "list" instead of "array", arrays are something different in Python.

Comment: To make something a code block, you select the code, then hit the `{ }` icon at the top.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that you are calling int on `arg[0]`. Now, `arg` is what's left over from the initial loop, when you went through all the arguments in `sys.argv` - it's the last element from that loop. So, when you slice it with `[0]`, you are in fact getting the first character from the last argument, rather than - as you intended - the first argument.

Your fix is to simply use `sys.argv[1]` there instead.

Comment: Ah yes, that fixed my problem. Thanks! I still have the problem of not being able to add a print line to my ValueError

Answer (score 3):

You're re-using your loop variable, `arg`, so you're accessing the first character of `sys.argv[1]`, instead of the whole string.  Try:

```
try:
    argNumber = int(sys.argv[1])
except ValueError:
    argNumber = 0
```

I don't see the "This is wrong" line in your snippet, so I can't really comment on that.

Finally, placing 4 spaces in front of every line is the only way right now.  It'd be nice if they supported some style of code fencing (like GitHub), but they don't. :-(

Comment: The way it's written here, it works fine.  Either you mixed tabs and spaces, or it's not lined up correctly in your original source code.

Comment: Well I'm getting an error there "IndentationError: unexpected indent" all I use are tabs, and it got exactly 1 tab just like the line above it (Notepad++ even acknowledges that by giving me association lines with ValueError)

Comment: Can you show the full exception that you get?  The caret (`^`) in the exception shows you where the problem is.

Comment: the ^ is directly underneath the p of print.

Comment: As I said before, something is mixed up here.  Maybe try turning on the [display of unprintable characters](http://npp-community.tuxfamily.org/documentation/notepad-user-manual/display/unprintable-characters)?  There is something that Python doesn't appreciate in there.  You could also look at the line with a hex editor.  It looks like there's a plugin for NP++ that [provides hex editing support](http://npp-plugins.sourceforge.net/).  That could be illuminating.

Answer (score 2):

After the loop runs, arg contains the value of the last argument passed, as string.

In your specific case, `arg = '92'`. so when you do `arg[0]`, you get `'9'` and `arg[1]` gives you `'2'`

Use `sys.argv[1]` in case you need the first argument.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `arg[0]` is the first elemente of the string assigned to `arg`. In your code this was the last command line argument.

Use `int(arg)` to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

After this loop

```
for arg in sys.argv:
    print arg
```

`arg` is the last command line argument. It's a string, so using e.g. `arg[0]` gets the first character in that string.